# Java Applet application - Update x Paint methods

Tags: java, swing, applet

I'm starting to learn Java game development, currently following [this](http://www.kilobolt.com/unit-2-creating-a-game-i.html) great tutorial.

The game developed is Applet based.

After some researching, I discovered that an Applet is heavy weight Component Swing Using UIManager.

So, when I read the repaint() documentation, which says:

```
repaint():

Repaints this component.
If this component is a lightweight component, this method
causes a call to this component's <code>paint</code>
method as soon as possible.  Otherwise, this method causes
a call to this component's <code>update</code> method as soon
as possible.
```

I understand that repaint() calls update(), as the Applet is a heavy weight component, and not paint().

BUT

on the game tutorial, the writer/'teacher' says:

"*... The paint() will similarly be always called, with the repaint() statement within the run() method. ...*"

This indeed appears to be happening. But why is repaint() calling paint()?

Follows the code (trimmed for the important parts).

Thanks

```
public class StartingClass extends Applet implements Runnable, {

private Robot robot;
private Image image, character;
private URL base;
private Graphics second;

@Override
public void init() {

    setSize(800, 480);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setTitle("Q-Bot Alpha");

    base = getDocumentBase();
    character = getImage(base, "data/character.png");

}

@Override
public void start() {

    robot = new Robot();

    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();

}

@Override
public void stop() {

}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {

        robot.update();

        repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

@Override

public void update(Graphics g) {

    if (image == null) {

        image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());         
        second = image.getGraphics();

    }

    second.setColor(getBackground());
    second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    second.setColor(getForeground());
    paint(second);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {     

    g.drawImage(character, robot.getCenterX() - 61, robot.getCenterY() - 63, this);

}

}
```

Comment: Read: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) an advanced tutorial on AWT and Swing graphics.

Comment: But also know that AWT (such as your Applet) uses technology that is 20 yrs out of date, while Swing is only 5-10 yrs out of date.

Comment: Ok. My goal is to learn game basic framwork, to then go to Android.

Comment: Then sorry to say, but I don't think that you should bother learning Applet game programming as I doubt that much that you learn will be transmissible to Android. I'd focus on Java and Android basics and then Android game programming.

Comment: I started with this one because was the best game tutorial I found on the internet. Do you know any good one for Android?

Comment: Nope, sorry but I do not.